# Displaying Total Author View

Tags: author-template

I'm looking to display the total views generated by each author on their author page. I can't find any php code that works. Can anyone help?

I've tried using this code:

```
<?php
$author_posts = get_posts( array('author' => $current_user->ID) );

$counter = 0; // needed to collect the total sum of views

foreach ( $author_posts as $post ) {

    $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) );
    $counter += $views;
}
echo "{$counter}";
?>
```

but the number displayed stays on '0'. Am I doing something obvious wrong?
Here's one of my author pages: http://fresharsenal.com/author/olipricebates/

Any help greatly appreciated! Also if anyone knows how to show the amount of shares generated that'd be ace

Answer (score 1):

The `$current_user` object retrieves the currently signed-in user.  What you want is the ID of the author whose page you're viewing.  Try this:

```
global $wp_query;
$author_id = $wp_query->queried_object_id;

$author_posts = get_posts( array('author' => $author_id) );

$counter = 0; // needed to collect the total sum of views

foreach ( $author_posts as $post ) {

    $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) );
    $counter += $views;
}

echo "{$counter}";
```

Echo out views, to see if there are any:

```
foreach ( $author_posts as $post ) {

    $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) );

    var_dump($views);

    $counter += $views;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still showing '0'

Comment: http://fresharsenal.com/author/umarwilshere/
http://fresharsenal.com/author/olipricebates/

Comment: Echo out `$views` in your foreach loop, are you showing any?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: Look at my edit above.

Comment: If 'echo out' means remove that code - I have done that but it still shows '0'

Comment: nope, add `var_dump($views);` to your foreach loop, so you can verify there are actual views being stored for each post.

Comment: OK I've added this code and now it shows: 'int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0) int(0)' http://fresharsenal.com/author/olipricebates/

Comment: Ok, so that means there are no views being stored per post.  Are you using a plugin to store post views?

Comment: Yes I recently started using 'Post Profit Stats' Which shows views by author
The traditional wp-pageviews is blocked by my host

Comment: Well for some reason, views aren't being stored or `post_views_count` isn't the correct meta_key to query on.

Comment: Anyway of finding out whats right? I've now added a 'views' count at the top of each article. It can be seen here: http://fresharsenal.com/arsenal-set-to-complete-important-deal-amid-deadline-day-distraction/